# Getting an unresolved external symbol when compiling c++ class

Tags: c++, linker, unresolved-external

I have the following classA.h

```
#ifndef ClassAH
#define ClassAH
class A
{
public :
      A();
     ~A();
      static std::map< std::string, std::vector< string > > getSomething();
}
#endif
```

and the implementation in classA.cpp

```
#include classA.h

std::map< std::string, std::vetor< string > > classA::getSomething()
{
   //implementation

   return map
}
```

Now I have another class classB.cpp in which I am doing :

```
#include classA.h
void method1()
{
   std::map< std::string, std::vector< string > > map = classA::getSomething();
}
```

Note getSomething() is static.

when I compile classB
I am getting error LNK2019 on the method getSomething() saying unresolved external symbol ....referenced in method1().

What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

in `classA.cpp` you just declared global function. You must include `A::` in definition:

```
std::map< std::string, std::vector< string > > A::getSomething() 
{
    return map;
}
```

This way compiler knows that method `getSomething()` belongs to the class `A`

Comment: actually I did include A:: in my definition,  ( I forgot it in my original post now I edited the question ) but still getting the error when I call this in a classB.cpp

Comment: your class is `A` but in code you typed classA::

Comment: never mind I resolved it. I had to modify a definition file. Thanks.